# Selectively getting text from <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <p>I need get<strong>this</strong>
        <a title="And this" href="#">but not this</a>
    </p>
    <p>And also<strong>This</strong>
        <a title="And this" href="#">but not this</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

How do I grab everything in p tag except for the text in nested a tag. And also I need to get values for "title" attirbute for tag a?

Comment: And what do you want to do with it all? What've you tried?

Comment: Trying to generate "text-only" email based on html text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('.myDiv a').text('');
$('.myDiv p').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text()+$('a',this).attr('title'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cBejv/)** example.

Comment: Make sure you clone the object, I don't think you can change the links on the page, but it does work.

Comment: @JuanMendes - I suppose it depends on exactly how the OP plans to use the final result and the input which he hasn't really described other than 'generate "text-only" email'.

Comment: The most logical assumption is that the OP doesn't want to damage the existing page, isn't it? But in any case, your answer does mention the real meat of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

- Creates a clone
- Replaces the a tags with their title attributes
- Calls text() on the cloned node

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/cBejv/2/

```
var clone = $('.myDiv p').clone();
clone.find('a').replaceWith(function() {
   return this.getAttribute('title');
})
console.log(clone.text());
```

Outputs

```
I need get this

 And this And also This

 And this
```

Comment: +1 - Yeah, this fits better for the OP. The point is that if you clone the top level node, you can manipulate the clone however you want in order to create the text based email.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work. There may be a much better way to do this, but this was the first thing to come to mind.

```
var $clone = $('.myDiv').clone();

$clone.find('a').remove();

$('#output').append($clone.text());​
```

Make sure you add an element with `id="output"` to see the results.

Comment: Looks like the simplest way to do it... oops, actually it looks like the OP needs the text from the title of the A tag also